# list is not getting sorted using IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparable

This is my abstract base class:

```
public abstract class BaseDataModel<T> : System.IComparable<T> where T : BaseDataModel<T>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }


    #region IComparable<T> Members

    public virtual int CompareTo(T other)
    {
        return ID.CompareTo(other.ID);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This class represents Person and imherits from the BaseDataModel class.

```
public class Person : BaseDataModel<Person>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

But when i am trying to sort the List using sort() method, it doesnt work. It returns the sorted list with 2 objects but all the properties in those objects are null.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> pList = new List<Person>();

        Person p = new Person();
        p.ID=2;
        p.Name="Z";
        pList.Add(p);

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p.ID = 1;
        p.Name = "A";
        pList.Add(p1);

        pList.Sort();





        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: list contains objects with null values. It does show 2 objects but all the attributes are null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the properties of `p` twice; you never set `p1.ID`.

Comment: ouch. i guess i need to calm down.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
  Person p = new Person();
    p.ID=2;
    p.Name="Z";
    pList.Add(p);

    Person p1 = new Person();
    p.ID = 1;
    p.Name = "A";
    pList.Add(p1);
```

This should be:

```
  Person p = new Person();
    p.ID=2;
    p.Name="Z";
    pList.Add(p);

    Person p1 = new Person();
    // Change properties of p1, not p!
    p1.ID = 1;
    p1.Name = "A";
    pList.Add(p1);
```